# how to set autolayout for label between 2 stack view?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am a beginner, and I really need your help. `autolayout` for `UILabel` really really confused me :(

I want the end result to be like this in `portrait` in all `iPhone` Device.

[image]

I have made "attend" and "09:00" to be one stack view, and make it vertically in container and 8 point leading space to container like this
[image]

I also have made "running" and "7h 32m" to be another one `stackview`, and make it vertically in container and 8 point trailing space to container like this 
[image]

so I think that 2 stack view will always be in that position.

I also have 2 `UIView` as a vertical line, and it has 8 point gap to each `stackview`.

the problem is in the middle part, especially "example note example note example note ". I want that note `UILabel` to be 8 point gap to the each vertical line. but when I add 8 point gap to the each vertical line, the those 2 stack view shifted and I dont understand why. could you please help me why this is happened?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: NO need to set autolayout in stackview. it automatically set your uiviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag three `UIView` to `StoryBoard`. Name it as, `ATTENDVIEW`, `NOTEVIEW` and `RUNNINGVIEW`

Select all the three and Embed in `StackView`.

`StackView` axis is `Horizontal`, alignment and distribution as `FILL`, spacing 2.

Set `StackView` Constraints as, top 15, left and right is 0, height as 70.

Set `Width` `Constraints` as 70 for, `ATTENDVIEW` and `RUNNINGVIEW`. Dont give any constraints to `NOTEVIEW`.

For both `ATTENDVIEW` and `RUNNINGVIEW`, add single UILabel each. Name it as, `AttendTextLabel` and `RunningTextLabel` .

For, both, `AttendTextLabel` and `RunningTextLabel`, set numberOfLines as 2 and Constraints as top, bottom, left and right as 4.

**Coding**

```
    //ATTRIBUTE TEXT FOR UILABEL - USE THIS FOR TWO LABEL
    let main_string = "Attend\n09:00"
    let string_to_color = "09:00"

    let range = (main_string as NSString).range(of: string_to_color)

    let attribute = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: main_string)

    attribute.addAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white], range: range)

    AttendTextLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

    AttendTextLabel.attributedText = attribute
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Output**

[image]